# Do not trigger rxjs chain on change

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got the following code to perform an ajax search:

```js
// Observable for search terms
searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

// Observable to perform actual search
articles$ = this.searchTerm$.pipe(
  switchMap(filter => this.getArticles(filter)))

// Set a new search term
searchArticles(searchTerm: string) {
  this.searchTerm$.next(searchTerm);
}
```

Then, in the template, I use this:

```html
<input type="text"
  [ngModel]="selectedArticle"
  (ngModelChange)="selectedArticle = $event; searchTerm$.next($event)"
  [typeahead]="articles$" />
```

The typeahead I use is [the one from Valor](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead). The component subscribes to `articles$`, which works fine, but because I trigger a new event on search, instead of just caching the searchTerm, the dropdown opens again when I select something.

So, somehow, I need to make `this.searchTerm$` 'lazy', and make `article$` just use that value when it's subscribed to. I thought about `withLatest`, but since my first argument would depend on my second one, that's not an option.

I have the feeling the solution is really simple, but I just cannot see it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do to be honest. `Subject` doesn't store any value so if there're no subscriptions emissions with ` searchTerm$.next($event)` are simply lost.

Comment: I don't understand your exact question. Probably you are looking for BehaviorSubject.

Comment: @martin The typeahead subscribes to articles$ to get its data, which triggers when the textbox changes. Also, on these changes, `searchTerm$.next` is called, which pipes into articles$.

What I guess I'm looking for, is something like a delegate observable, e.g. `Observable.of(x => this.variable)` ... which I could actually do, come to think of it...

Comment: Maybe you could just use the `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, by making the the searchTerm$ observable a callback:

```js
// Observable for search terms
searchTerm$ = new BehaviorSubject<() => string>(() =>
  this.searchTerm);

// Observable to perform actual search
articles$ = this.searchTerm$.pipe(
  switchMap(filter => this.getArticles(filter())))

// Set a new search term
searchArticles(searchTerm: string) {
  this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
}
```